# change chef server install location

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am installing chef server using cookbook chef-server from supermarket.
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-server

in my wrapper cookbook I did

```
    node.override['chef-server']['configuration'] = <<-EOS
install_path "/my_privateChefS/"
EOS
```

after I've done chef-client, I can see there is an entry in /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb

```
install_path "/my_privateChefS/"
```

However, when I ran 
    chef-server-ctl reconfigure
I did not see "/my_privateChefS/" is created, and it clearly uses default "/opt/opscode" everywhere. Do I miss something using the cookbook?

How do I change the install location of chef-server?
I am changing it as worrying about the disk space as cookbook grows, should I? which chef `data` directory I should move if not the install directory?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the folder we install things to, just the data and other active state folders. In general omnibus packages are not relocatable. Either reconfigure the data folder or mount the other FS over the existing one.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "the data folder"? 
Where can i find this setting somewhere?

Comment: If you're running a stock Chef Server (i.e. not chef-backend) and you are concerned about cookbook file data, the bookshelf data path is what you need to change: https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server_optional_settings.html#bookshelf